# Connection problems on wired connection but everything is fine on wireless connection

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, internet-connection, wired

I have a weird problem on my Win7 machine that I couldnt find any solutions for.

I have a router with built-in modem and a built-in wireless.

My problem is as follows: When my PC is directly connected to my router through a cable I get many connection problems, among these:

- Windows update never works and gives error 8024402F, according to microsoft site this is WU_E_PT_ECP_SUCCEEDED_WITH_ERRORS
- Certain websites dont work correctly, for example when accessing the new outlook.com I often get a connection error. After refreshing a few times and eventually get in, clicking on any email message never displays it.
- When I search using Bing.com or Google.com sometimes I get 1-2 entries of results and my browser seems to be still fetching data but nothing is fetched, I have to refresh again to get the whole page to complete.
- Many sites simply give me connection errors where I have to refresh multiple times for them to show up.
- Some https sites don't work.

When I use wireless connection to my router, all of the above problems disappear and everything works fine.

When connected through cable, if I go to **Network and Sharing Center** then under **View your basic network information and set up connections** I click on **See full map** I get the following diagram:

MyPC ---> Hub ---> BRCOM Router ---> Internet

When connected through wireless, the diagram is as follows:

MyPC ---> My Access Point Name ---> Internet

My question is as follows:

Could this be a problem with the cable I am using? I currently don't have another cable so I cannot test another one unless someone tells me that this could be a possible cause. ***(Edit: I used another cable and tried all 4 slots in the router. Did not fix)***

Could this be a problem with the network driver? I have used the dell website for my PC to fetsh the latest driver for my network card.

Could this be a different problem in routing?

Any ideas?

**Edit:**

I don't know why there is a 'Hub'. Physically, my PC is directly connected to my router which has a built-in modem and is also my wireless AP. My router is directly connected to my phone line. So physical diagram is:

My PC ---> Router(includes Buit-in modem, includes wireless) ---> phone line

Comment: you show the AP and router both connected to the Internet. 
This is unlikely. Can you do one diagram that includes both devices?

Comment: I think this is a faulty cable, replace it, don't think too much in to it.

Comment: Broadcom doesn't make routers... they make chips FOR routers... so what kind of router is this really?

Comment: @TheCompWiz Clearly, it's whatever cable modem his ISP provided for his **home** broadband connection.  Needs to be moved to SuperUser.

Comment: @Paul Ackerman see my edit above

Comment: @Alex Berry I tried a new cable with same problem

Comment: @TheCompWiz That's how it is listed in the map, my router was provided by my ISP and it is a SAGEMCOM F@AST 2048

Comment: When wired, are you seeing packet loss when you try to ping the router? Try running `ping -n 50 <routerip>`, where `<routerip>` is the internal IP of your router, usually `192.168.0.1` or `192.168.1.1` or similar.

Comment: @Darth Android I have run ping -n 50 192.168.1.1 no packet losses.

Comment: You might try repeating it over Wifi, though it should give you the same back, with slightly higher response times. From a wired connection, try `ping -n 50 8.8.8.8` and `ping -n 50 google.com` to see if either of those give you issues with packet loss. (8.8.8.8 is the google public dns server)

Comment: @Darth Android Thanks for the reply. I am not getting any packet losses for 8.8.8.8 or google.com whether using wired or wireless connection